# TypeError: split() takes no keyword arguments in Python 2.x

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split

I am trying to separate a section of a document into its different components which are separated by ampersands. This is what I have:

```
name,function,range,w,h,k,frac,constraint = str.split(str="&", num=8)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: split() takes no keyword arguments
```

Can someone explain the error to me and also provide an alternate method for me to make this work?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The parameters of [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) are called `sep` and `maxsplit`:

```
str.split(sep="&", maxsplit=8)
```

But you can only use the parameter names like this in Python 3.x.  In Python 2.x, you need to do:

```
str.split("&", 8)
```

which in my opinion is the best for both versions since using the names is really just redundant.  `str.split` is a very well known tool in Python, so I doubt any Python programmers will have trouble understanding what the arguments to the method mean.

Also, you should avoid making user-defined names the same as one of the built-in names.  Doing this overshadows the built-in and makes it unusable in the current scope.  So, I'd pick a different name for your string besides `str`.

Comment: Not only is there no reason to specify the names, it is actually an error to do so (at least in Python 2.x, don't know about 3.x) even if you use the names that the doc uses, `sep` and `maxsplit`.  Accordingly, note that the error says "*no* keyword arguments".

Comment: Huh.  It works in 3.x, so I thought it would work in 2.x as well.  Updated.

Comment: It's also particularly important to de-confuse new users about not using the name `str`, because `str.split` *does* exist as an unbound method.  I expect the OP has been told "oh, you should use `str.split()`" which *is* true, but can be taken wrongly....

Comment: This was not working for me with Python 3.2.  It turns out that it changed between Python 3.2 and 3.3.  In 3.2 they are [positional arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), but for 3.3 they changed to [keyword arguments](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 1):

The error states that you can't provide named arguments to `split`. You have to call `split` with just the arguments - without the names of the arguments:

```
name,function,range,w,h,k,frac,constraint = str.split("&", 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

split  doesnt get keyword arguments `str` or `num`. Do this instead:

```
name,function,range,w,h,k,frac,constraint  = str.split('&', 8)
```